# Media Queries on Android

Tags: android, responsive-design

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 550px)
```

is a simple query, correct?  With reference to what it should do. I am using it to swap an `a:href` with one that is set to `display:none`.

Works fine on any IPhone, IPod or Android with a 3rd party browser, but on a standard Android it only works on the initial page load, after that it ignores the style.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`max-device-width` isn't well supported in native Android browsers. Would `max-width` be an acceptable alternative?